# How can I debug with JRebel in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jrebel

When I debug with the Jrebel in IDEA, it always goes wrong with

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\swlims-lims1\target\web.xml (System couldn't find the file )  when Artifact is being deployed

but when I debug with the button by Tomcat, it doesn't happen like this, it works right without this exception.
System couldn't find web.xml usually caused by which reasons .Thx

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: No idea what exactly you are talking about. I would suggest you either turn to jrebel or to intellij support.

Answer (score 0):

You might try getting IDEA to generate the `rebel.xml`.  Right click on the project in intellij, scroll down to bottom of context menu 'JRebel' then select `rebel.xml`.

This file tells JRebel where your classpaths and webapp (containing web.xml) are located.